# If a moderator unilaterally deletes Meta questions about deleted main site questions, where ought I post my worries?

Tags: support, meta, deleted-questions, moderators

I'm addled why there are comments with "you falsely claimed", and they're upvoted. The title of post unmistakably states "a moderator unilaterally deletes Meta questions", and I've never edited it. I screenshot the deleted questions to elucidate.

[image]

[image]

### [image]

A moderator at Quantitative Finance deleted https://quant.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1644 that questions the deletion of the https://quant.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1642, https://quant.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1641.

The moderator [left a comment](https://quant.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1642/which-textbook-proves-that-prtouch-approx-2-times-prprobability-of-in-the?noredirect=1#comment1802_1642) on one of the now-deleted meta questions:

> We have discussed this exact same question before. Specific questions are not a topic for meta. Discuss in the comments on the main site.

1. How can I "Discuss in the comments on the main site" if the original question is now deleted?
2. If a moderator deletes Meta questions on why main site questions were closed, then where else can I possibly question such closures?

Comment: "Specific questions are not a topic for meta." - Yeah, I have to side with you on that one, that's nonsense. Pretty much all the Meta sites I visit actually *have* a [tag:specific-question] tag for exactly that purpose.

Comment: Why do I get a feeling that some important piece of information is missing?

Comment: Where those three  questions closed for the same reason? You realize that many users will be unable to see any of those posts you listed. We only have your side.

Comment: Your [question](https://quant.stackexchange.com/q/54242/35) was automatically *deleted by Community*. In fact, the question was closed via *five non-moderator votes*. It was not deleted by the moderator, as you falsely claimed.

Comment: We have [explained to you](https://quant.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1633/35) repeatedly that Quant.SE is for professionals in quantitative finance. We have one simple rule: You must work in this industry to post on here. (We modeled that after [Theoretical Computer Science](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/tour).) You do not work in this field and the level of your questions reflects that.

Comment: Related context: https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6610/why-do-so-many-identify-this-questions-feature-odd-or-archaic-words-for-landscap

Comment: @chrisaycock "It was not deleted by the moderator, as you falsely claimed." A moderator deleted https://quant.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1644.

Comment: The original question was not deleted by a moderator as you falsely claim. I suggest you read the Quant.SE tour to figure out what is wrong with your questions because I'm not going to spend much time on moderating your trolling. Furthermore, you fail to interact or learn from the answers on previous questions you asked on Meta.

Comment: Maybe quantitative finance should rename itself to professional quantitative finance to make it more clear what the site is about.

Comment: @chrisaycock That's important information, can you please put that in an answer? Comments don't necessarily last forever, while answers last.

Comment: @Mast I was literally in the process of writing my answer last night when this question was closed. My two comments are the salvaged versions of my answer.

Comment: @chrisaycock Oh, right, that makes sense.

Answer (score 6):

First of all, I'll hit the obvious answers:

- > How can I "Discuss in the comments on the main site" if the original question is now deleted?

  This would probably be exactly the sort of question that you *should* be asking on their meta.
- > If a moderator deletes Meta questions on why main site questions were closed, then where else can I possibly question such closures?

  If you feel that a moderator is acting inappropriately, you can always contact the community team directly via https://meta.stackexchange.com/contact, and they will investigate.

---

That said, it's important to note that not all meta sites are run the same. While I agree with many that meta is the perfect place for "specific-question" questions, I am not a member of the Quantitative Finance Stack Exchange site, nor do I claim any expertise in how they choose to run it. If a moderator says that specific-question questions are not welcome on their meta, I would totally defer to their expertise in this case.

If the site, for whatever reason, has determined that specific-question discussions should be held in the comments on that question, then that's where said discussions should be held. The fact that you are unable to hold said discussion on a deleted question doesn't change that, nor does the fact that you presumably lack the privileges to undelete it and solve the problem yourself. Policies, as well as minimum requirements for certain privileges, may be frustrating but they're there for a reason.

If you disagree with the policy, well, that's entirely within your rights. Discussing *that* is totally what the per-site meta is (or should be) for.

Comment: But meta is the one place to go and ask why a question was closed or deleted on the main site. It's there in place so the question page doesn't become a squabble  arena. Isn't this why comments are said to be ephemeral, SE is  not supposed to be a forum. Meta is the arena where discussions can be held. On the other hand, comments on the main site are for asking the OP to clarify, to supply supporting evidence, to expound further. etc. A moderator cannot  change the function or nature of meta. Why?

Comment: @Mari meta is the place to ask about deleted questions on main, true, but when one abuse that and keep asking *after being told they're not welcome to post*, the mod has the right to stop them. And that person can always take it to SE staff using the contact form.

Comment: @Shadow Like I said earlier, in a comment, I feel some important piece of information was missing. Nevertheless,  I was disputing the hypothesis that it  is up to the discretion of a moderator to decide whether a post's validity should be discussed on the main page.

Comment: @Mari-LouA I said no such thing. I merely said that I would defer to the moderator's expertise as to what sort of behaviour their site does or does not welcome, not that the moderator has any right to unilaterally set policy.

Comment: Then I misunderstood the part which reads: `If the site, for whatever reason, has determined that specific-question discussions should be held in the comments on that question, then that's where said discussions should be held.` It seems to suggest that a community, of which its moderators are an integral part, might decide that  the discussion be deferred to the main page. That is how I interpreted it. Was I wrong? Maybe?